# Connect WinForms project with WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I need to connect a WPF project with a WinForms project.

I have one project done in WinForms ("ClassRoom") and another project done in WPF ("ActivityRoom"). In the WinForms project I've got a form called `MainForm` and in WPF project I have a window called `MainWindow`.

I need to open the `MainWindow` by clicking a button in `MainForm`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you mean WPF with Winforms ?

Comment: Yes, but both forms are in 2 separate projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just open the window the same way as from the WPF application directly:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var wpfWindow = new WpfProject.MainWindow();
    wpfWindow.Show();
}
```

You will need to add references to the WPF assemblies to your WinForms project for this to work.

Also note that this will just open the window. It won't run any code for your App.xaml.cs, if you have any.